# <unknown> is not a numpy array error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy, computer-vision

I am trying to apply threshold to an image, but I get the following error :

> TypeError: 'unknown' is not a numpy array

I get this error on the cv2.imshow() line.

Here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('...',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('...',0)
fImg = cv2.addWeighted(img.astype(np.float32), 0.9, img2.astype(np.float32), 0.1, -20.0)
th = cv2.threshold(fImg, 127, 255, cv2.TRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('th', th)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cv2.threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold) returns a tuple (retval, dst), where dst is the transformed matrix. You need to pass `dst` to `cv2.imshow` instead of the returned tupled, after checking if `retval` is valid

```
retval, th = cv2.threshold(fImg, 127, 255, cv2.TRESH_BINARY)
if retval:
    cv2.imshow('th', th)
```